# How to assign loaded tables to different variables in a loop in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to import `n` tables with a loop, giving a different name for each table.

I can write the code to import the tables but I can't give a different name for each table:

1. the path to find the files (csv)

   ```
   totalbaseURL=('path')
   ```
2. find all the csv files

   ```
   folders = os.listdir(totalbaseURL)
   ```

   i.e., `folders` becomes `["house","cars","food","pubs"]`.
3. `folders` contains the name of the csv files

   ```
   for f in folders:        
       path=totalbaseURL+f
       table=pd.read_csv(path,delimiter=';')
   ```

How could I put, instead of "table"? I would like to use the names in `folders`: (`house`, `cars`, `food`, `pubs`).

Comment: To associate strings with values, use a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dict,

```
folders=["house","cars","food","pubs"]

di = {}

for f in folders:        
    path=totalbaseURL+f
    di[f]=pd.read_csv(path,delimiter=';')
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use a dict to achieve it:

```
dataframe_dict = {}
totalbaseURL=('path')
folders = os.listdir(totalbaseURL)
for f in folders:
    path=totalbaseURL+f
    dataframe_dict[f]=pd.read_csv(path,delimiter=';')
print dataframe_dict
```

Output:

```
{"house": DataFrame1, "cars": DataFrame2, "food": DataFrame3, "pubs": DataFrame4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
for f in folders:        
    path = os.path.join(totalbaseURL, f)
    globals()[f] = pd.read_csv(path, delimiter=';')
```

This will create global variables `house`, `cars`, `food`, and `pubs`. If this code is inside a function, use `locals()` instead of `globals()`.